# Connect to Picasa from Android

Tags: android, picasa

I want to connect to Picasa from an Android application (without interacting with any third-party application).

I tried to Google it and found no tutorial / explanation.

Even in [Picasa Web API site](http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/overview.html) there is no explanations for Android.

I will really appreciate any tutorial / sample code / instructions.

Thank you.

Michael.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definitely check out the source code for Google's sample Photostream application, part of the [apps-for-android](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/) sample code pack. In particular, the [Flickr.java](http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/source/browse/trunk/Photostream/src/com/google/android/photostream/Flickr.java) file from that project should give you a pretty good handle on how to call a Web service from an Android application.

The code's mostly from late 2008, so it's not cutting-edge Android 2.1 code, but you're going to want to support Android 1.5 minimum for at least a few months more anyways.

Comment: WOW! Thanks for the apps-for-android.